# How to insert the data into sqlite database after entering in background in with objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

Code which am using are as follows

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(addContacts) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

-(void)addContacts
{
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")",
                               @"Anu", @"0009", @"Hyderabad"];

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt,
                           -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {


        }
        else {

            }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }

else
{
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Information Alert"
                                                      message:@"Please enter the name "
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];
}
}
```

But its not working when its in the background

Answer (score 0):

You can do that technically by enabling background tasks. But apple allows background modes for certain tasks only such as location services, music, voip etc. If you fake a music or some other allowed task to do this, your app may be rejected.

Comment: Is there is any way to run the database in the background

Answer (score 0):

You can tell iOS that you intend to perform a short-lived background task without any extra background modes. Use UIApplication's [`beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler%3a) at the start and then call [`endBackgroundTask:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/endBackgroundTask%3a) when you're done. iOS does not guarantee that you will be allowed to perform your background task. For more information, see the documentation of those methods.

Comment: Jesper beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler is used to continue running method even after the application enters to background I would like to insert the data to database 10 sec after entering to background

Comment: Yes, so use that method, then start a timer for 10 seconds and do what you need to do.